# how to assign specific colors for the same set of columns (y-axis in bar chart) that appear in different dataframes

Tags: pandas, bar-chart, colorbar

I'm doing an analysis on F1 pit stop times and want to plot 3 bar charts with teams on the y-axis and pit times on x-axis for year 2022, 2021, 2020. since the teams are the same, I want to assign team official colors to team column once and have the colors automatically populated in the charts.

each year's dataframe looks like this:
[image]

I made the table in SQL and first made it into a pivot table in pd:

```
import pandas as pd 
import seaborn as sns 
import matplotlib as plt

fastest_pit_2020_pivot = pd.pivot_table(
    data=fastest_pit_2020,
    columns="team",
    values="avg_pit_time",
)
fastest_pit_2020_pivot
```

then i plotted it but currently manually assigning the colors

```
fastest_pit_2020.plot(kind='bar', x="team", y="avg_pit_time", ylim=(23,26),color=["#1E5BC6","#2293D1","#4E7C9B","#6CD3BF","#ED1C24","#2D826D","#F58020","#37BEDD","#B12039","#B6BABD"])
```

[image]
i don't mind assigning colors manually but i know there's probably an easier/smarter way to do this (and to impress my prof) so looking for some help here.

thanks!!!

Comment: Hi Tako welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve]. In particular share your data as code not pictures